# Why does the location of a external css stylesheet matter?

Tags: css, image

I'm a beginner programmer and have looked at several resources, but I can't figure out why location of a external css stylesheet matters. For example, changing the link to the file and the location of the file, respectively, will determine if a picture loads or not:

A simple line in the css:

```
body {
    background: url(./images/test.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
}
```

This will load a picture:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

This will not:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

Why?

Comment: There is no images folder in the css folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because there is no `images` folder inside your `css` folder. It's relative to the `css` file, not the `html` file.

You can fix it like so:

```
body {
    background: url(../images/test.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
}
```

This goes up to the root directory first, then into the images folder.

Then you can use your css line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: You're response was the most informative. Thanks for answering is so thoroughly.

Comment: No problem, what we're here for.

Answer (score 2):

The image location is relative to the CSS file's location, not the HTML file's location.

Comment: +1 - The . in the path refers to the current directory (where the css file is). You need a hardcoded path (/images/test.jpg) or a relative path down a directory (../images/test.jpg)